# Parents relative Node Distance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the *Node Distance* of a parent element.

If I use `$(element).parents()`, I get an array of 5 results:

[image: As so]

I need to get the node distance `#content` relative to the current element. What would be the simplest solution?

Comment: A simple loop iterating each `parent()` in turn, until you hit the element, would do the job.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Man, was hoping for a simple `.parentDistance()` jQuery method I missed out on.

Comment: How about jquery `parentsuntil()`?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Haha you tell me that just as I write a method..

Comment: You should work slower :) That was only 1 min after your comment

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Haha if only that was my manager's attitude ;) Anyway, posted an answer with credits to you.

Answer (score 1):

One option will be to traverse the parents until you find the required element, then bring back the count:

```
var s = $(element).parents()
var i = 0;

$.each(s, function(index, element){
    if(element.id === "content"){
       i = index;
    }
})
```

Thanks to @TrueBlueAussie for pointing out `.parentsUntil()`

`$(element).parentsUntil("#content").length`

**Edit:** Keep in mind that the top method will return `0` for a direct parent, and the bottom will return `1`